Angular Material 18 - Mat-paginator [length] issue
I have a problem with the mat-paginator component.


displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
  totalItems = 0;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private colorService: ColorsHttpService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    
    this.loadData(1, 10);
  }

  loadData(pageNumber: number, pageSize: number) {
    this.colorService.getColors(pageNumber, pageSize).subscribe(response => {
      this.dataSource.data = response.items;
      this.totalItems = response.paging.totalItems;
      this.paginator.pageIndex = response.paging.pageNumber - 1;
      this.paginator.length = response.paging.totalRows;

      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }

  onPageChange(event: any) {
    this.loadData(event.pageIndex + 1, event.pageSize);
  }
<mat-paginator [length]="totalItems"
                   [pageSize]="10"
                   [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                   (page)="onPageChange($event)">
    </mat-paginator>



I set the number of items in the component, but in the view I see that the number of items is 0.

However, when I try to change manualy (using UI) the page size (without page refreshing), the data starts showing correctly and paging works perfectly.

What could be the cause?
Why is mat-paginator not initializing correctly?

the api might be returning incorrect values, please share the api response during screen load for checking

You are setting totalItems to be the array of objects returned by the API. Instead your totalItems should be the length of this array, as below:
this.totalItems = response.paging.totalItems.length

